# Swift: iPad Air device Bool configuration?

Tags: swift

Alright, so I've created a sprite kit game in Swift and I'm fixing the configurations for the different devices. So far I've done this using the following extension:

```
extension UIDevice{
    var iPad2:Bool {
        return UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad && UIScreen.mainScreen().scale == 1.0
    }
    var iPadRetina:Bool {
        return UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad && UIScreen.mainScreen().scale == 2.0
    }
    var iPhone6plus:Bool {
        return UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone && UIScreen.mainScreen().nativeBounds.height == 2208
    }
    var iPhone4s:Bool {
        return UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone && UIScreen.mainScreen().nativeBounds.height == 960
    }

}
```

and if statements such as:

```
if UIDevice().iPad2 {
//resize stuff for the ipad2
}
```

Everything works great except for I'm having trouble finding the configuration to put in the `UIDevice` extension for the iPadAir `var` so that I can call an if statement like

```
if UIDevice().iPadAir {
}
```

Can't find it anywhere.

What would I put inside `var iPadAir:Bool` within the `UIDevice` extension?